# How can I prevent accessibility voiceover from reading out the selected cell position in a collection view?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, tvos, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I would like the disable the behavior where the accessibility voiceover reads out the cell's position in a collection view (I'm developing for tvOS, but its probably the same behavior in iOS)

e.g. When the first cell is selected/focused (from a total of 3 items), voice over is reading "one of three".

The accessibility mode I need to support is Follow Focus.

I have already tried setting the cell's:

```swift
isAccessibilityElement = false
accessibilityTraits = .none
```

Comment: Are you setting it in tableviewcell for iOS?

Comment: @crvo84: do your cells contain simple content like text or are there other stuff like images, buttons... provide an example in order to be as accurate as possible in the answer, please. 

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.accessibilityElementsHidden = YES;
```

From the the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615080-accessibilityelementshidden):

> The default value for this property is false. You might use this property to hide views that are covered by the arrival of a new view. In this case, the hidden views might remain visible onscreen, but they are not the focus of the user’s actions.

You might also use this property to hide a transient view that VoiceOver users don’t need to notice. For example, VoiceOver doesn’t need to describe the translucent view that appears when users adjust the volume on their devices, because the aural feedback of this action is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

On your cell you can try

```
accessibilityElementsHidden = true
```

for disable accessibility behavior for this cell.

But if you still want accessibility in your app, try changing the text that Voice Over will spell by setting accessibility label

```
accessibilityLabel = "some text that will be spoken by voiceover"
```

This may change whatever Voice Over will speak